# No operator matches "*" error when using pointers and vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Trying to pass a vector by using a pointer to a function however I receive the error:

```
E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands
```

Pretty sure I am referencing correctly too so I'm not sure why it is happening.

Here's the code:

```
public:
SortingData Sort(vector<double> *newVect, int arraySize, char choice)
{
    clock_t timer;
    double duration;

    cout << "Insertion Sort:" << endl;
    int i, key, j;
    if (choice == 'a')
    {
        timer = clock();
        for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
            key = *newVect[i];
            j = i - 1;


            checks++;
            while (j >= 0 && *newVect[j] > key) {
                checks++;
                *newVect[j + 1] = *newVect[j];
                j = j - 1;
                swaps++;
            }
            swaps++;
            *newVect[j + 1] = key;
            cout << *newVect[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 'd')
    {
        timer = clock();
        for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
            key = *newVect[i];
            j = i - 1;


            checks++;
            swaps++;
            while (j >= 0 && *newVect[j] < key) {
                checks++;
                *newVect[j + 1] = *newVect[j];
                j = j - 1;
                swaps++;
            }
            *newVect[j + 1] = key;
        }
    }


    duration = (clock() - timer) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << *newVect[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Checks: " << checks << endl;
    cout << "Swaps: " << swaps << endl;
    cout << "Time to complete: " << duration;
    return {"Insertion Sort",checks,swaps,duration};
 }
};
```

Here's how I call the function:

```
returnedData[2] = insertionSort.Sort(&data, elementTotal, orderChoice);
```

Comment: Where's the declaration of `returnedData` and of your parameter `data`?

Comment: @ClickRick declaration of returned data and parameter for data happen before the function is called but there's nothing wrong with them as the function works without pointers just fine

Comment: You could avoid this issue by not using pass-by-pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscription operator `[]` has a higher precedence than the dereference operator `*` (cf., for example, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) reference). Hence, `*newVect[i]` is the same as `*(newVect[i])`, which makes no sense here. So you'd have to write `(*newVect)[i]` here in order to first dereference the pointer to your vector before applying the subscription operator `[i]` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error occur? Is it where you access items of the vector?

Try `(*newVect)[i]` to first dereference the pointer to the vector and then access the index within the vector.

The indexing operator `[]` has a higher precedence than the dereferencing operator `*`. Thus when you write `*newVect[i]` it first tries to access the ith element in the pointer (ie the ith vector in an array of vectors, this would probably result in a runtime error) and then dereference that. But it can't because `newVect[i]` would be of type `vector<double>` which you can't dereference with the `*`operator.

Maybe, if you need to pass a modifyable vector to a method, you are better off, passing a reference instead of a pointer.

```
SortingData Sort(vector<double> &newVect, int arraySize, char choice)
```

And call it like

```
returnedData[2] = insertionSort.Sort(data, elementTotal, orderChoice)
```

Then you don't need to dereference the pointer when you use the vector and access the elements.

And you also might not need to pass the `arraySize` parameter, because `vector::size()` returns the number of elements in a vector.

Comment: The only problem with using referencing was that I have multiple classes and function with different sorting algorithms and when I run them all at once for some reason the actual vector that I'm referencing not the reference gets sorted which is what I don't that's why I tried using pointers and came to this error.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to run different sorting algorithms on the same input. But if you pass a pointer to the original vector you will have the same issue as with passing a reference. If you want to keep the original vector, you will have to make a copy before passing it to your sorting methods (or make a copy inside your sorting methods).